# Obtaining message processor ip

Tags: apigee

We're trying to add an originating ip address target request and I wasn't able to find how to access the ip address of the message processor. I did find this in the documentation: system.interface.{interface_name} but I'm not sure if that would yield what I want nor do I know what the correct interface_name would be.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please send an email to help@apigee.com with the name of the org you are using and it will be forwarded on to send you the IP addresses of the message processors.